# " AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'integer' " getting this error while running tensorboard from command prompt

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard, object-detection-api

While running the commamd : `tensorboard --logdir=training/`
I am getting some error in code.

Tried updating the numpy library.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
            File "/home/apoorva/.local/bin/tensorboard", 
line 6, in <module>
    from tensorboard.main import run_main
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/main.py", line 42, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 63, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.framework_lib import *  # pylint: disable=redefined-builtin
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/framework_lib.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework.ops import Graph
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.eager import context
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/context.py", line 30, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.framework import c_api_util
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/c_api_util.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.util import compat
  File "/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/compat.py", line 129, in <module>
    integral_types = (_numbers.Integral, _np.integer)
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'integer'
```

numpy version : 1.16.2
tensorboard : 1.13.1
tensorflow : 1.13.1

I expect tensorboard interface to pop-up.

Comment: Is the numpy module reference in the current environment the right one? you may use the following bash script to find out `python -c 'import numpy  as np; print(np.__file__)'`

Comment: ```/home/apoorva/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py```
getting this after running the above command